# Distribute calculated value to multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

```
Table of projects

ProjectID, SOP,     IncomeA, IncomeB
1          2021-01  100.000      0
2          2022-11    5.000  2.000
```

```
Table of income per year per project

ProjectID, SOPOffset, Price, Volumn
1          0          10     1.000
1          1          10     2.000
2          0          15     1.000
2          1          20       500
2          2          20       500
```

The column `SOPOffset` is relative to the year of the column `SOP`. So project 1 has income in 2021 and 2022 while project 2 has income in 2022, 2023 and 2024.

The result of an existing query is

```
year  income
2021  1.000 -- #1 offset 0
2022  3.000 -- #1 offset 1 + #2 offset 0
2023    500 -- #2 offset 1
2024    500 -- #2 offset 2
```

A new requirement is that the columns `IncomeA` and `IncomeB` needs to be distributed to a maximum of 3 years per project. That means that project 1 with 2 `SOPOffset`s will add `50.000` to year 2021 and 2022 while project 2 with 3 `SOPOffset`s will add 2333.34 to year 2022 and 2333.33 to year 2023 and 2024

```
year  income
2021  51.000    -- #1 offset 0 + (100.000 + 0)/2
2022  55.333,34 -- #1 offset 1 + #2 offset 0 + (100.000 + 0)/2 + 7000/3 (rounded up to 2333,34)
2023   2,833,34 -- #2 offset 1 + 7000/3 (rounded down to 2333,33)
2024   2,833,34 -- #2 offset 2 + 7000/3 (rounded down to 2333,33)
```

Is this new requirement possible in a single query? My current solution is implemented in the application code itself or using loops, etc in SQL.

**Edit 03.08.2020 15:30**
As requested in a comment, this is the existing query which uses a slightly different table structure and some additional information to build the full result set

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(cp.datSOP) + pv.intYearOffset,
    SUM(pv.decPrice / cr.decRate * pv.intVolume) as IntakeEUR
FROM
    tblProjectVolume pv
    INNER JOIN tblProject sp ON sp.intProjectId = pv.intProjectId
        INNER JOIN tblCustomerProject cp ON cp.intCustomerProjectId = sp.intCustomerProjectId AND (YEAR(cp.datSOP) + pv.intYearOffset >= 2019)
    INNER JOIN tblCurrency c ON c.intCurrencyId = sp.intCurrencyId
        INNER JOIN tblCurrencyRate cr ON cr.intCurrencyId = c.intCurrencyId AND cr.intYear = 2019
group by
    YEAR(cp.datSOP) + pv.intYearOffset
order by 
    YEAR(cp.datSOP) + pv.intYearOffset
```

The detailed result has an additional join and group by

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(cp.datSOP) + pv.intYearOffset, bu.intBusinessDivisionId,
    SUM(pv.decPrice / cr.decRate * pv.intVolume) as IntakeEUR
FROM
    tblProjectVolume pv
    INNER JOIN tblProject sp ON sp.intProjectId = pv.intProjectId
        INNER JOIN tblCustomerProject cp ON cp.intCustomerProjectId = sp.intCustomerProjectId AND (YEAR(cp.datSOP) + pv.intYearOffset >= 2019)
    INNER JOIN tblCurrency c ON c.intCurrencyId = sp.intCurrencyId
        INNER JOIN tblCurrencyRate cr ON cr.intCurrencyId = c.intCurrencyId AND cr.intYear = 2019
    INNER JOIN tblProductMapping pm ON pm.intProductMappingId = sp.intProductMappingId
        INNER JOIN tblBusinessUnit bu ON bu.intBusinessUnitId = pm.intBusinessUnitId
group by
    YEAR(cp.datSOP) + pv.intYearOffset, bu.intBusinessDivisionId
order by 
    YEAR(cp.datSOP) + pv.intYearOffset, bu.intBusinessDivisionId
```

Comment: can you show your existing query ? Please also explain how do you obtain the result for the current query

Comment: @Squirrel I've added it to the initial posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the key point is you need to distribute the Income by no of years. First you need to find out the number of years. This is done in the CTE `income`, it uses `count()` to determine no of offsets per Project. Once you have that, just divide the Total Income by that

```
declare @projects table
(
    ProjectID   int,
    SOP     int,
    IncomeA     decimal(10,2),
    IncomeB     decimal(10,2)
)

declare @income table
(
    ProjectID   int,
    SOPOffset   int,
    Income      decimal(10,2)
)

insert into @projects
values  (1, 2021, 100000,    0),
        (2, 2022,   5000, 2000)

insert into @income
values  (1, 0, 1000),
    (1, 1, 2000),
    (2, 0, 1000),
    (2, 1,  500),
    (2, 2,  500)

; with income as
(
    select  ProjectID, SOPOffset, Income, 
            TotalOffset = count(*) over (partition by ProjectID)
    from    @income
)
select  year    = (p.SOP + i.SOPOffset),
       income   = SUM(  i.Income
                     +  ((p.IncomeA + p.IncomeB) / i.TotalOffset) )
from    @projects p
        inner join income i on  p.ProjectID = i.ProjectID
group by (p.SOP + i.SOPOffset)
```

PS : I come up with the query before you posted your actual query. I am sure you will be able to adapt that according to your query

Comment: Thanks for that solution, but that would be too easy ;) It misses two requierments: (a) distribute the value to a max of 3 years and (b) in a single query. (a) could be solved with an `IIF` at `TotalOffset` count. But (b) is a bit more problematic, I think - and not, embedding the `with income` into `from` of the select statement is unfortunately not a solution...

Comment: the solution that i have posted is one single query only. Or what do you mean exactly by `in a single query` ?

Comment: Due to a changed requirement I can use your solution with a small change (requarding A). Previously the query had to be implemented in SQL and in a DB framework used by the application, which is only able to execute single queries with limited functionallity.